# Inserting nodes with equal keys in a B-tree

Tags: algorithm, treenode, b-tree, clrs

I am trying to insert 3 4s into an empty B-tree. t = 3. I tried some applets online but all thay do is insert 4 once and then just drop 4. Is it the way it has been implemented in CLRS as I did not completely understand their pseudocode.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for: the result, or code to do the insertion?

Comment: i am looking for the result. Suppose the tree only has 4 at its root. I want to add another 4 to the tree. what is the result?

Comment: Just do a standard insertion, pretending that the new 4 is, say, smaller than all the other 4's or bigger than all the other 4's. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When *N* has become 3 and you do the fourth insert, the root node has to be split, with at least N/2 nodes remaining in it and in each  new leaf node. So the result must be a tree with 1 key in the root, and two leaves with 1 and 2 keys in them respectively, in either order depending on whether you regard a duplicate key as coming before or after the existing duplicates. Normally it would be after ...